# Using Angularjs with jquerymobile not able go back with the back button

Tags: jquery-mobile, button, angularjs, routes, back

Hello friends i m using angularjs with jquery mobile in my app and done routing with mobileangular adapter javascript that will handle routing (jquery-mobile-angular-adapter-standalone.js).

i have used angularjs for data binding , underscorejs for data processing  and routing for my dynamic template. My app work well with routing in forward direction but when i use
back button which to not carry back to my previous page. my url shown in address bar is the same that of previous page but page do not display with previous data
i m placing all my code below

**index.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="work">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    s
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/components/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter-standalone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/components/angular-resource.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/components/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app/controllers.js"></script>   
    <script src="js/app/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
    </div>
</body>
</html>


html use to display da
```

**showMenuView.html**

```
<div id="menu-list" data-role="page" ng-controller="showMenuController">
    <div data-role="header">
         <a href="" data-icon="back" data-rel="back">Back</a>
     </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li ng-repeat="menuItem in mainMenuItems">
                <a href="/showMenu/{{menuItem.parent}}" data-rel="external" data-transition="slide" ng-click="selectMenuItem(menuItem._id)">{{menuItem.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p>Total {{mainMenuItems.length}} menu item</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller.js**

```
'use strict';

function showMenuController($scope, $location, Data, $routeParams) {


  Data.query(function(data) {
    $scope.foo = data;

    $scope.mainMenuItems = _.where($scope.foo.menuItems, {parent:$routeParams.parent}); 
  });


  $scope.selectMenuItem = function (id) {
       $scope.mainMenuItems = _.where($scope.foo.menuItems, {parent:id});
   }

}
```

**service.js**

```
angular.module('dataservices', ['ngResource']).  
 factory('Data', function($resource){
         return $resource('data/data.json', {}, {
             query: {method:'GET',isArray:false}
        });

});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('work', ['dataservices'])
       .config(['$locationProvider','$routeProvider', function($locationProvider,$routeProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
            $routeProvider
                //.when('/showMenu', {parent:'none',templateUrl: 'showMenuView.html', jqmOptions: { transition: 'slide'}})
                .when('/showMenu/:parent', {templateUrl: 'showMenuView.html', jqmOptions: { transition: 'slide'}})
                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/showMenu/none'})
                ;

        }]);
```

pls help me ,thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't the `$location` service conflict with jQuery Mobile navigation model? Try to disable one of them if you can (probably the jQuery Mobile one).

Comment: what if i use $ http instead of location

Comment: `$http` has a different purpose. If I were you, I'd try first to disable the built-in jQuery Mobile navigation and see if it can work like that. If not, try disabling Angular routing and use the jQuery Mobile navigation.

Comment: Have you got solution for this issue? I am facing the same issue, i was using routing with AngularJS and jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked on it myself, but while exploring on whether JQM and angular can work together I stumbled upon this page.

http://simonguest.com/2013/04/08/jquery-mobile-and-angularjs-working-together/

he makes a good point (i.e. both angular and JQM uses and manipulates the url) that appears to be valid in your case also. he suggests to let JQM do this. I think you can also use different special character to process url i.e. angular uses ! and JQM uses # or something like that.